# Graph from adjacency list

Tags: r, list, graph, adjacency-list

I have a adjacency list and I want to visualize them and do processing on it. Is there a package to do it efficiently. I see there are lot of graph packages but confused among them. Can someone help me on this?

```
$`825`
[1] 824

$`824`
[1] 823

$`823`
[1] 822

$`822`
[1] 821

$`821`
[1] 820 777

$`820`
[1] 819 816 789 787 785 783

$`777`
[1] 776
```

Above is the adjacency list. Below is the graph I want.

```
825
 |
824
 |          _______ 783
823        /
 |        /________ 785
822      /
 |      /__________ 787
821 -- 820
 |      \__________ 789
777      \
 |        \________ 816
776        \
            \______ 819
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? Give us the data in a form we can cut and paste to recreate it (see help(dput)). Also, the short answer is probably package:igraph

Comment: `igraph` and `statnet` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 mylist <- list(2,c(1,3),c(2,4),c(3,1))
 names(mylist) <- c(1,2,3,4)
 # just like your list

 #make it in the igraph format
 myadj <- stack(mylist)

#>    values ind
#>     1      2   1
#>     2      1   2
#>     3      3   2
#>     4      2   3
#>     5      4   3
#>     6      3   4
#>     7      1   4

 #plot it
 library(igraph)
 g<-graph.data.frame(myadj)
 plot(g)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... How can I change the size of the nodes??

Comment: with   `plot(g,vertex.size=10)` or
`V(g)$size <- c(3,6,9,20);  plot(g)` . for good help look up the documentation by typing `?igraph`